# Why does the behavior of array syntax differ from '(?,?)' syntax when updating a point field and that field is NULL?

Tags: postgresql, update, datatypes, postgresql-9.3

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.5.

Suppose I have the following table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE point_test ("name" varchar(255), "pt" point);
```

I then insert a row, leaving `pt` `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO point_test (name) VALUES ('me');
```

Then, I want to update `pt` using the array-like syntax:

```
UPDATE point_test SET pt[0] = 42, pt[1] = -42 WHERE name = 'me';
```

which appears to succeed (`UPDATE 1`) - `EXPLAIN VERBOSE` shows the following:

```
Update on pg_temp_65.point_test  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=538)
  ->  Seq Scan on pg_temp_65.point_test  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=538)
        Output: name, (pt[0] := 42::double precision)[1] := (-42)::double precision, ctid
        Filter: ((point_test.name)::text = 'me'::text)
```

However, `pt` is still `NULL`. If I use a slightly different syntax, it works in this case:

```
UPDATE point_test SET pt = '(42,-42)' WHERE name = 'me';
```

results in the point `(42,-42)` as expected.

Further, now that there is something in the field, I can update the point using the first syntax:

```
UPDATE point_test SET pt[0] = 84, pt[1] = -84 WHERE name = 'me';
```

results in the point `(84,-84)` as expected.

**Why do the behaviors of the two syntaxes differ only when the `pt` column is `NULL`?**

Comment: I presume this is because there's a difference between `null` and a `point` having both components being `null`.

Comment: Please re-run with `RETURNING *` on both, e.g. `UPDATE ... RETURNING *`, and update the question. I tend to agree with Colin though.

Comment: @Colin'tHart That's what I initially thought too, but try: `SELECT point(NULL, NULL) IS NULL;`. It's true.

Comment: It might be a bug. At least it looks like an inconsistency that's worth to be reported as such. The doc says we can subscript `point` with the array-like syntax, but in a super-concise way with no mention of updates or special cases for nulls.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: The point is that components of ([currently existing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html)) geometric types cannot be NULL. Only the whole value can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html)

> It is possible to access the two component numbers of a point as
>   though the point were an array with indexes 0 and 1.

But geometric types are *not* arrays.
 While the value as a whole can be `NULL`, parts of a point (or any [geometric type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6547)) **cannot**.

All geometric types can be input as **string literals** and cast to the respective type. None of them accept `NULL` as part of the input. This results in an **error message**:

```
SELECT '(NULL,1)'::point;
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type point: "(NULL,1)"
>   LINE 1: SELECT '(NULL,1)'::point

On the other hand, if you try passing one or more NULL values to a **constructor function**, you get **`NULL` for the whole value** - which is a bit inconsistent, but still makes sense: if one component is unknown, the whole value is unknown. All of these tests return `TRUE`:

```
SELECT point(NULL, NULL) IS NULL
      ,point(1, NULL) IS NULL
      ,point(NULL, 1) IS NULL
      ,point(NULL, 1) IS NULL
      ,circle(point(1, 1), NULL) IS NULL;
```

This leaves the case where an **`UPDATE`** silently ignores an assignment of NULL to `pt[0]` or `pt[1]`. This should really do one of two things:

- Set the `point` to `NULL` - like `SELECT point(NULL,1)` does.
- Raise an exception - like `SELECT '(NULL,1)'::point` does.

I would say this is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: In my question, `pt[0]` and `pt[1]` are both set in the same statement (i.e. `pt` would be valid and non-null) - could you imagine a third case where the `UPDATE` succeeds?

Comment: Obviously, you cannot `UPDATE´ *parts* of a geometric data type that is `NULL` - even if you update all parts. You would have to update the *whole* value as one to make it non-null. And not sure I understand your last question in the comment.

Comment: I was just referring to the two bullet points at the end of your answer, and imagining a third case wherein a valid assignment to `pt` succeeded. My thinking was that the context of a statement or transaction could allow an update of `pt` "as one," despite being written piecemeal using array syntax, but I see your point.