# Array of strings when updating a field

Tags: postgresql, update, datatypes, array, row

Unintentionally discovered that following query works in PostgreSQL:

```
UPDATE "sometable" SET "somefield" = ('string1', 'string2') WHERE "id" = 1;
```

I'm passing an array of strings to field and the result is a string of '("string1","string2")', not an array as expected, at least then using php extension pgsql.

How this happens and that does `('string1', 'string2')` means in PostgreSQL? I don't think this works in other SQL RDBMSes.

Comment: Please show us the complete `create table` statement of the table `sometable`. Regarding the `(...)` syntax, please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS  The manual also explains how to use arrays: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS

Answer (score 2):

> I'm passing an array of strings ...

You are ***not*** passing an array, at least not a Postgres array type.
An **array literal** would look like this:

```
'{string1, string2}'
```

You can type it explicitly:

```
'{string1, string2}'::text[]
```

The same can be achieved with an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) in most places:

```
ARRAY['string1', 'string2']
```

*This* is constructing a row (of type "anonymous record"):

```
('string1', 'string2')
```

It's short syntax for a [ROW constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
ROW('string1', 'string2')
```

And can, in similar fashion be provided as string literal (**row literal**) as well:

```
'(string1,string2)'
```

Each of those anonymous records can be cast to a well know row type:

```
'(string1,string2)'::my_row_type
```

In the `UPDATE` statement Postgres coerces the value to the data type of the target column or raises an exception if that cannot be done. If `sometable.somefield` is data type `text`, the text representation of the above row is saved, which is  `'("string1","string2")'`. Double quotes are only added where necessary to keep the syntax unambiguous.

Related:

- [Why does the behavior of array syntax differ from '(?,?)' syntax when updating a point field and that field is NULL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73631/why-does-the-behavior-of-array-syntax-differ-from-syntax-when-updating-a/73676#73676)
- [PostgreSQL: Issue with passing array to procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963380/postgresql-issue-with-passing-array-to-procedure)