# Cross-product between table column and input values

Tags: postgresql, join, set-returning-functions

I seem to be unable to write an `SQL` query, which computes the cross-product between a table column and a set of given input values.

Something along the lines of:

```
WITH {1,2} as Input
Select *
From mTable.column, Input
```

With `mTable.column` containing the values `3` and `4`, it should return:

```
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In other RDBMS (like SQL Server before 2008 - as per Paul's comment) one might cross join to a subquery with `UNION ALL SELECT`, but there are more convenient and efficient options in Postgres.

And you don't need a CTE for this. You can use it, but it has no performance benefit.

1. Provide a *set* with [`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html):

   > `VALUES` computes a row value or set of row values specified by value
   >   expressions. It is most commonly used to generate a "constant table"
   >   within a larger command, but it can be used on its own.

   ```
   SELECT t.i, m.col1
   FROM   mTable m
   CROSS  JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) t(i);
   ```
2. Provide an *array* and [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

   2a. with an [array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

   ```
   SELECT i, m.col1
   FROM   mTable m
   CROSS  JOIN unnest (ARRAY[1,2]) i;
   ```

   2b. With an array literal:

   ```
   SELECT i, m.col1
   FROM   mTable m
   CROSS  JOIN unnest ('{1,2}'::int[]) i;
   ```

Add `ORDER BY i, m.col1` if you need the sort order in your result.

About row and array syntax:

- [Array of strings when updating a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114549/array-of-strings-when-updating-a-field/114562#114562)

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is a `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT input.n, mTable.column
FROM mTable, (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS n) AS input;
```

.. or, in more modern SQL notation,

```
SELECT input.n, mTable.column
FROM mTable
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS n) AS input;
```

It's essentially a join without join conditions and it displays the cartesian product of mTable and input, similar to `INNER JOIN ... ON 1=1`.

You may also be able to use [the `LATERAL` construct](http://blog.heapanalytics.com/postgresqls-powerful-new-join-type-lateral/) for potentially better performance, but PostgreSQL isn't my strong card.