# POSTGRES declaring variable containing date array in functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, array

I am trying to declare a date array.

I have tried this:

```
DECLARE
dateVal DATE[] := ['2018-01-01','2018-02-01'];
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
```

How do I properly declare it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use ARRAY keyword:

```
create table tbl (dateval date[]);
insert into tbl values(array ['20180101','20180102'::date]);
```

Or in a block of code:

```
do $$
declare 
    dateval date[];
begin
    dateval := array ['20180101','20180102'::date];
end;
$$;
```

Or cast the expression as an array of dates.

```
do $$
declare 
    dateval date[];
begin
    dateval := '{2015-4-12, 2015-4-19}'::date[];
end;
$$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5d3fac6226f1486ffa483ab261a22321)*

Answer (score 5):

Assign the variable at declaration time if it's known at declaration time. Else it's initialized with NULL and you need another statement to assign it. A small waste of code and performance.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   dateval date[] := '{2015-4-12, 2015-4-19}';
BEGIN
   -- do something
END
$$;
```

You just need the right syntax for *either* an **array literal** *or* an **[ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS)**.

The string literal above needs no explicit cast, since the type is defined in the assignment implicitly.

Related:

- [Array of strings when updating a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114549/array-of-strings-when-updating-a-field/114562#114562)