# How to pass an array to trigger function in TG_ARGV?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql, array

I've got some fairly generic Postgres trigger functions that I'd like to re-use across a few different tables. To that end, I'm passing arguments as part of the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement so they'll be available in the `TG_ARGV` array, [as described in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html).

This works fine as long as all of my arguments are scalars, but there are a couple of them that really should be represented as arrays.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    special_names text[];
    special_users text[];
BEGIN
  special_names := TG_ARGV[0];
  special_users := TG_ARGV[1];
  IF NEW.name = ANY(special_names) THEN
    NEW.name = 'special';
  END IF;
  IF NEW.user = ANY(special_users) THEN
    NEW.user = 'flag';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER on_create_flag_special
BEFORE INSERT ON example_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE example_function(
    ARRAY['magicname1', 'magicname2']::text[],
    ARRAY['user1', 'user2']::text[]
);
```

Postgres complains with:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
>
> LINE 5:  ARRAY['magicname1', 'magicname2']::text[],

In other contexts, that's valid syntax for an array literal (e.g. `SELECT ARRAY['magicname1', 'magicname2']::text[];` works fine). I've also tried using other syntax varieties, like `'{"magicname1", "magicname2"}'::text[]` but without any success.

Can anyone suggest a good approach for passing an array parameter to a trigger function? Is it just impossible and I should give up and encode/decode via a JSON string or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string_to_array()` in your solution is only useful if you want to allow non-standard array syntax. Else it's simpler and cheaper to just cast. And you can do the assignment at declaration time. Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_function()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    special_names text[] := TG_ARGV[0]::text[];
    special_users text[] := TG_ARGV[1]::text[];
BEGIN
   IF NEW.name = ANY(special_names) THEN
      NEW.name = 'special';
   END IF;
   IF NEW.user = ANY(special_users) THEN
      NEW.user = 'flag';
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

Use proper array syntax in the trigger as suggested by Jeff:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_create_flag_special
BEFORE INSERT ON example_table
FOR EACH ROW                             
EXECUTE FUNCTION example_function(
    '{magicname1,magicname2}',        
    '{user1,user2}'
);
```

`{magicname1,magicname2}` is standard text representation of arrays in Postgres for input and output.

A trigger takes **string** arguments. We have to pass an array literal, not an array constructor. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> `arguments`
>
> An optional comma-separated list of arguments to be provided to the
> function when the trigger is executed. The arguments are literal
> string constants. Simple names and numeric constants can be written
> here, too, but they will all be converted to strings. Please check the
> description of the implementation language of the trigger function to
> find out how these arguments can be accessed within the function; it
> might be different from normal function arguments.

An [array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) needs to be *executed* to build an array from the input list, and we cannot execute anything in a DDL SQL call. We need to pass a literal string. See:

- [Array of strings when updating a field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114549/array-of-strings-when-updating-a-field/114562#114562)

These trigger arguments are completely separate from normal function arguments. In fact, trigger functions are created without arguments. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> Note that the function must be declared with no arguments even if it
> expects to receive some arguments specified in `CREATE TRIGGER` — such
> arguments are passed via `TG_ARGV`, as described below.

The array literal is then cast to an actual array in the function: `TG_ARGV[0]::text[]`.

About `EXECUTE FUNCTION` vs. `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307492/trigger-uses-a-procedure-or-a-function/307500#307500)

Comment: Can you explain why {a,b,c} is the syntax, and not ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'] which is what seems to be postgres array syntax in other scenarios.

Comment: @xpusostomos The trigger takes a *string* argument, so you have to pass an array literal, not an array constructor. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114562/3684

Comment: Hmm... the trigger function is declared without explicit arguments, and you have to extract them with TG_ARGV. Surely you should be able to pass anything you want and have it pop out in TG_ARGV.... and it's not like '{a,b}'  pops out in TG_ARGV as a string, it seems to pop out as an actually array. Perhaps  it's too much to ask why the behavior is so esoteric, but I don't really get how supposedly ARRAY['a','b'] is creates a thing in Postgres, but it isn't accepted in some cases.

Comment: It's not even as if it gives an error "wrong type" or some such, it's syntax error, as if the parser never heard of ARRAY[] before.

Comment: @xpusostomos: *"and it's not like '{a,b}' pops out in TG_ARGV as a string"*. But that's exactly how it is. I added more explanation, yet. Please follow the links to the manual.

Comment: OK, so it really is a string. That doesn't explain why a programming environment wants you to program arrays in strings when it actually has a legit array type.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the pure string representation of the array.

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_create_flag_special
BEFORE INSERT ON example_table
FOR EACH ROW                             
EXECUTE PROCEDURE example_function(
    '{magicname1,magicname2}',        
    '{user1,user2}'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

@bjmc this is what you should have done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    special_names text[];
    special_users text[];
BEGIN
  special_names := TG_ARGV[0]::text[];
  special_users := TG_ARGV[1]::text[];
  IF NEW.name = ANY(special_names) THEN
    NEW.name = 'special';
  END IF;
  IF NEW.user = ANY(special_users) THEN
    NEW.user = 'flag';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER on_create_flag_special
BEFORE INSERT ON example_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE example_function(
    '{magicname1, magicname2}',
    '{user1, user2}'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this question, I wound up encoding my arrays as strings and then using [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.16.1.1.1) to decode inside the trigger function.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    special_names text[];
    special_users text[];
BEGIN
  special_names := string_to_array(TG_ARGV[0], ', ');
  special_users := string_to_array(TG_ARGV[1], ', ');
  IF NEW.name = ANY(special_names) THEN
    NEW.name = 'special';
  END IF;
  IF NEW.user = ANY(special_users) THEN
    NEW.user = 'flag';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER on_create_flag_special
BEFORE INSERT ON example_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE example_function(
    'magicname1, magicname2',
    'user1, user2'
);
```

This feels slightly like a hack, but it seems to work fine.

Comment: that's not the way to do it. I'll show you below what you should have done.