# Advantages of POINT over DOUBLE for distance queries?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, spatial

I'm about to start an application that will need a simple distance query to order results. After some search I've discovered some [functions](http://johanndutoit.net/searching-in-a-radius-using-postgres/) that seems to do this work pretty easily without needing PostGIS, what seems to be too much for my task.

My question is: what would be better from a performance point of view, using a POINT datatype to store lat/long or two DOUBLE fields, separately? Would they have any difference?

Bonus question: is the approach from that link a nice idea indeed?

Comment: Sorry Erwin, I saw you replied but forgot to read :B Do you have any opinion over the functions on the link I cited?

Comment: I don't know the author of that blog. The [cube](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/cube.html) and [earthdistance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/earthdistance.html) modules have been around for more than 10 years and are solid. If approximate results are good enough, that's a valid option. The GiST index is the key feature. I would start by reading the manual on the two modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`point`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6730) consist of two [`double precision`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) values. You store the same information, same size on disk and in RAM. But with a slightly different set of constraints.

Two separate columns can be `NULL` or not independently. A point can only be NULL *as a whole*:

- [Why does the behavior of array syntax differ from '(?,?)' syntax when updating a point field and that field is NULL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73631/why-does-the-behavior-of-array-syntax-differ-from-syntax-when-updating-a/73676#73676)

You can use [geometric functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html) for points. But you can easily construct a point from two numbers on the fly: `point(x, y)`. In reverse, you can easily access coordinates of a `point` as `double precision` numbers: `p[0]`, `p[1]` (0-based index!)

It's basically a matter of taste and style while you don't use the more sophisticated types [`geometry` or `geography`](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry) provided by PostGis.